# How to put this dart class together so I can use it in different parts of my code

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to implement a Dio interceptor so I will be able to use it with my code.

I will be using this interceptor in many places. So I thought it would make sense to put it into a class or an interface whichever is best and just extend or implement it my subclasses.

I have this so far:

```
class AppInterceptor {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  AppInterceptor() {
    dio.interceptors
        .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (Options options) async {
        var token = await getAuthorizationToken();

        options.headers["Authorization"] = 'Bearer $token';
        return options;

    }, onResponse: (Response response) {
      // Finally, the string is parsed into a JSON object.
      //print(response.toString());
      return response;
    }, onError: (DioError e) {
      print('somthing went wrong');
      // Do something with response error
      return e; //continue
    }));
  }
}
```

How do I use this in a subclass to make an http call?

I tried something like this when trying to do my http call:

```
 Response response = await AppInterceptor.dio.post(Global.functionsUrl+'/auth/linkuseraccount/', data: {'hey': 'hello'});
  print(response);
```

It fails each time with  `Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [403]`

From my backend, I can tell that it fails because the interceptor didn't pass in the authentication header.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Hi @LearnToday, the problem does not seem to come from the architecture of your class but from the header itself; there's nothing wrong with this class in my opinion

Comment: I think I got it figured out. I needed to do the Http call with an instance of AppInterceptor(). It works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: you need dependency injection, take a look at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it).

Comment: @hiwajalal thank you, but I don't need that :)

Comment: @LearnToday yeah you can do it without it, but using a true singleton is better.

Comment: @LearnToday Can you post your answer how you did it. It will be useful for someone also